# Matrix Sorting c++

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix

I need to sort a matrix in c++ based on a specific column and it has to be as more performing as possible. 
This is the matrix

```
JobId;DueDate;RelDate;TardPenalty
1;575;4;1
2;563;70;2
3;483;1;8
4;519;68;1
5;540;64;10
6;546;126;8
7;550;2;6
8;563;70;4
9;470;9;6
10;480;21;3
11;489;6;6
12;593;29;10
13;532;37;7
14;591;25;10
15;468;7;1
16;570;26;1
17;498;73;5
18;504;0;4
19;510;5;10
20;541;15;8
21;583;13;3
22;532;37;3
23;534;42;8
24;585;16;4
25;491;8;5
26;584;66;9
27;563;70;7
28;555;40;3
29;475;65;8
30;549;27;6
```

which is stored in a `vector<vector> Rel[][4]`
I need to sort it for DueDate (Rel[][1]) and to keep track of the other data.
Can someone help me? I tried with the sort() function but it's not good for matrixes.

Thanks a lot

EDIT:
I made a matrix quicksort algorithm but it crashes, here it's my code

```
void quickSort(vector<vector<int>> arr, int left, int right) {
    int i = left, j = right;
    vector<int> tmp;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2][1];

    /* partition */
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i][1] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (arr[j][1] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
                tmp[l] = arr[i][l];
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
                arr[i][l] = arr[j][l];
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
                arr[j][l] = tmp[l];
            }

            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    /* recursion */
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an array of arrays of vector of vwctors? If you store the matrix as a vector of rows, writing a custom comparison for `sort` isn't difficult.

Comment: Yes it's a vector of rows, but I don't know how to write a performing sorting function

Comment: With `vector<vector>` you already threw performance out the window. Use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) or something.

Comment: If the format of Rel is fixed by your problem statement, you need to show us the *actual* definition. `vector<vector>` will not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like a matrix to me.  This looks like a series of records.  I would define a record:

```
struct Record
{
    int JobId;
    int DueDate;
    int RelDate;
    int TardPenalt
};
```

store the data as

```
std::vector<Record> Rel;
```

define a comparison function:

```
bool sortByDate( const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs )
{
    return lhs.DueDate < rhs.DueDate;
}
```

and sort using the standard function:

```
std::sort( Rel.begin(), Rel.end(), sortByDate );
```

If you make sortByDate inline, you are very unlikely to be able to do much better.